# Lower limit topology is a Hausdorff space $T_2$

Tags: general-topology

Could you help me with the following?

Consider lower limit topology $\mathcal{T} $ with basis $\mathcal{B} = \{ [a,b) \ | \ a,b \in \mathbb{R}, \ a<b  \}$

Show that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, x\neq y \ \  \exists U,V \in \mathcal{T} \ : \ x\in U, y \in V, U \cap V = \emptyset$.

To be honest, I don't know what to use here. (I'm new to topology.)

Comment: I think you mean  $U\cap V=\emptyset$ and not  $U\cap V\not=\emptyset$, don't you?

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Assume without loss of generality $x < y$. You need to find one interval $I_1 = [a, b)$ in which $x$ lies, and one $I_2 = [c, d)$ in which $y$ lies, such that $a < b \leq c < d.$ These are all real number, so you can choose $I_1, I_2$ as...

Comment: That's my problem. It's very easy for open intervals. But here, as you said, $b$ can be equal to $c$. Could I take $b=c= \frac{x+y}{2}$?

Comment: Yes. Or more generally, let $d := |x -y|$. Then any (lower-limit type) intervals I_1, I_2 centered at $x, y$ respectively with radius $\epsilon \leq \frac{d}{2}$ will do.

Comment: @Hagrid: You’re working too hard: when $x<y$ just take $U=[x,y)$ and $V=[y,y+1)$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: that is a beautiful suggestion. +1 for comment and solution.

Comment: Thanks! I’m lazy: I *like* easy solutions! (Good to see you still here.)

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this without actually choosing any intervals at all. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the usual topology on $\Bbb R$. For any $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$ we have

$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{a<x<b}[x,b)\;,$$

so $(a,b)\in\mathcal{T}$. Every $U\in\mathcal{E}$ is a union of open intervals, so $\mathcal{E}\subseteq\mathcal{T}$. Now let $x$ and $y$ be any distinct real numbers. We know that $\langle\Bbb R,\mathcal{E}\rangle$ is Hausdorff, so there are disjoint $U,V\in\mathcal{E}$ with $x\in U$ and $y\in V$. But we just showed that $\mathcal{E}\subseteq\mathcal{T}$, so $U,V\in\mathcal{T}$, and $\langle\Bbb R,\mathcal{T}\rangle$ is therefore Hausdorff.

The more general principle here is that if $\tau$ and $\tau'$ are topologies on the same set $X$, $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is Hausdorff, and $\tau\subseteq\tau'$, then $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ is also Hausdorff: $\tau$ already contains enough open sets to provide each pair of points of $X$ with disjoint open nbhds.

Comment: you forgot to add $, you will see (i couldn't edit because is one character)

Comment: @Cortizol: Thanks!